# lambda : i VS lambda i : i VS lambda i=i : i

Tags: python, lambda

Известно, что  данный код создаст x cо значениями ['oops', 'oops', 'oops']

```
flist = []
for i in range(3):
   flist.append(lambda : i)
i  =  'oops'
x =[f() for f in flist]
```

казалось бы все должно было бы решить такой вариант:

```
flist = []
for i in range(3):
   flist.append(lambda i : i)
i  =  'oops'
x =[f() for f in flist]
```

однако на выходе получаем пустой список!?!
и срабатывает только такой вариант, который как на меня против всякого здравого смысла и синтаксиса:

```
flist = []
for i in range(3):
   flist.append(lambda i=i : i)
i  =  'oops'
x =[f() for f in flist]
```

Именно он выдает x cо значениями [0, 1, 2]. Но ведь обычная запись лямбды именно такая:

```
lambda x,y : x+y
```

Помогите разобраться: почему в первом случае не синтаксическая ошибка, а связывание по имени и почему вместо "нормального" `lambda i : i`  надо писать `lambda i=i : i`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом случае будет создан список лямбд, возвращающих значение глобальной переменной `i` в момент их вызова. То есть значение последней итерации.

Во втором случае будет создан список лямбд, возвращающих значение своего аргумента `i`. В случае вызова без аргументов, вы должны получить ошибку `<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'i'`, а не пустой список.

А в третьем случае будет создан список лямбд, значение по умолчанию которых захватит значение переменной цикла - `[lambda i=0: i, lambda i=1: i, lambda i=2: i]`.

Comment: но ведь в описании лямбда функций первый вариант не встречается, насколько я понимаю? Или это подразумевается, что можно использовать переменные окружения в лямбда выражении? Я думал - что читается только то что В САМОМ лямбда выражении?
Есть ли ссыль на такое поведение?
Был бы весьма польщен!

Comment: да, вы правы - это я в http://pythontutor.com/ (пайтононлайн) делал. Второй вариант  действительно выдает ошибку в интерпретаторе..

Comment: У лямбда-выражения такие же правила разрешения имён, как и у обычной функции.

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, такое поведение называется "замыкание". Материалы легко нагугливаются по запросу наподобие "питон замыкание в лямбда-функции"